# Why don't these strings match!?! - PHP

Tags: php, string, comparison, operators

I have an if statement with several conditions:

```
if (
    (fncIsSet($row[0]['incident']) == $line[4]
     && fncIsSet($row[0]['id']) == $line[0]
     && fncIsSet($row[0]["code"]) == $line[2]
    )
    && (
        ($GLOBALS['postCheckList'] == 2
         && $row[0]['QAResult']=='Fail'
        )
        || ($GLOBALS['postCheckList'] != 2)
    )
){
```

I have a large list of items going through this piece of logic (5000+ values) and about 99.9% pass through as expected.

I've stepped through the debugger a dozen times so I can confirm that the first 2 conditions are passing but the third is failing:

```
fncIsSet($row[0]["code"]) == $line[2]
```

Here are the vars that it's trying to compare (copied straight from the source) with their Hex codes beneath them:

```
Ambulance-2
Ambulance-2
41 6D 62 75 6C 61 6E 63 65 2D 32 
41 6D 62 75 6C 61 6E 63 65 2D 32
```

WTF, right?  I can't see any reason why these aren't working especially when other very similar variables are passing through fine (ie Ambulance-1 and Ambulance-3).

Here is another example:

```
Anzemet
Anzemet
41 6E 7A 65 6D 65 74 
41 6E 7A 65 6D 65 74
```

Comment: What does fncIsSet() do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bet dollars to donuts you've got trailing whitespace issues. Try printing out your variables with delimiters on either end (pipes are always good), or using [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/var_dump) to deeply inspect your variables.

Comment: That fixed the first one - I swear I checked that as it was the issue for others.  However, I still have an issue with the second example 'Anzemet'

Comment: I got it, I just trimmed the variables everywhere I could and that did the trick. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) to see the exact content of your variables (+ type) and in case of string also the length.